# how to read pickle file

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling, pickle

I ran the following code as well as different version of same code but I keep running into this specific error: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.core.internals.managers'; 'pandas.core.internals' is not a package
**

Please see code below:
import pickle
pickle_off = open(r"C:\Users\database.pkl","rb")
df = pd.read_pickle(pickle_off)

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works:

```
import pickle
file_name = 'data.p'
with open(file_name,mode='rb') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
```